# Web Scraping Help - How can I convert to a CSV?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to webscrape some statistics for a school project, and need to put them into table form for analysis. I've been able to pull the required data, but have been unable to find a way to convert to a clean table. Essentially, the ideal output would be a CSV with the following columns, with a row for each "table" group, see below:

i.e., Col 1 = "id", Col 2 = "game_id" ... up to Col 45, and then 1 row for each block of data you can see in the devtool network response.

I'm very much new to python and not a coder by trade, so any guidance would be appreciated - I've pretty much read every post related to this topic and haven't been able to figure it out. Thank you in advance! :)

See below for code so far. When I try using .csv or anything, it says that the data is a "None" attribute. Have gotten to the point where I can pull the data, but am unable to get it in the table form above.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = <URL HERE>

headers = {
        'value': '*/*',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'cookie': 'cookie-consent=true'
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
import json

URL = 'https://www.breakingpoint.gg/api/trpc/playerStats.fetchPlayerStatsByGame,modes.fetchModes,playerStats.fetchPlayerStatsByGame,playerStats.fetchPlayerStatsByGame,playerStats.fetchPlayerStatsByGame,games.fetchTeamsGameHistory,search.findAll?batch=1&input=%7B%220%22%3A%7B%22json%22%3A%7B%22gameId%22%3A%2269c37b74-5bbc-45e6-ac2c-6ea8b5270ce4%22%7D%7D%2C%221%22%3A%7B%22json%22%3Anull%2C%22meta%22%3A%7B%22values%22%3A%5B%22undefined%22%5D%7D%7D%2C%222%22%3A%7B%22json%22%3A%7B%22gameId%22%3A%22167d90bb-b1d7-4c94-9653-2ecd3f946635%22%7D%7D%2C%223%22%3A%7B%22json%22%3A%7B%22gameId%22%3A%2235c9700c-57bb-4a34-a775-5a14faaf41ae%22%7D%7D%2C%224%22%3A%7B%22json%22%3A%7B%22gameId%22%3A%22153f7784-d4e1-4f3d-9815-5c0e02a6d0c3%22%7D%7D%2C%225%22%3A%7B%22json%22%3A%7B%22team1Id%22%3A11%2C%22team2Id%22%3A4%7D%7D%2C%226%22%3A%7B%22json%22%3A%7B%22searchTerm%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D%7D'

headers = {
    'value': '*/*',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'cookie': 'cookie-consent=true'
}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
data = response.json()

import pandas as pd
# Use pandas to normalize the JSON data into a DataFrame
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# Explode the 'result.data.json' column to have one row per entry
df = df.explode("result.data.json")

# Normalize the exploded data further
normalized_data = pd.json_normalize(df['result.data.json'])

# Print the resulting normalized data
print(normalized_data)
```

The pd.json_normalize() function is used to flatten the nested JSON structure in the data dictionary and convert it into a pandas DataFrame (df). This creates a DataFrame with columns corresponding to the keys in the JSON data.

The explode() function is used to transform the DataFrame by expanding the rows based on the values in the specified column (result.data.json). This is done to handle cases where the column contains lists or nested structures, creating a new row for each element in the list.

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful, appreciate it! It's close - when I run this, looks like the pandas dataframe is still 1 level too high (i.e, returns a 7x37 matrix, with nested matrices inside ) - any ideas on how to pull out each individual matrix that's nested inside?

Comment: Edited my answer. I've exploded + normalized the table twice to only get the inner matrices

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much! Time to dig through and learn to to do this myself - really appreciate the help here :)